# Reduce function wrapping data in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I have a reduce function that formats my data in the way i need but the only issue is the data is nested inside an array. I need to remove the outter array or just stop the reduce function from adding it in but every attempt Ive made to stop the reducer from wrapping the data in an array breaks my code. Ideally I would like my reducer to not wrap the data in an array but if thats not possible removing the array i need from inside the reducer cleanly seems like the only solution:

my data looks like this:

```
{
  count: 4,
  datapoints: [
    {
      Date: "2021-05-05",
      score: 0,
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-05-12",
      score: 0,
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-05-30",
      score: 0,
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-06-03",
      score: 114,
    },
  ],
};
```

my reducer function and api call:

```
const riskScores = await api.PCC.riskAssessment(userID, startdate, endDate);

const riskScoresFormatted = riskScores.datapoints.reduce((result, data) => {
        const scores = result["riskAssessment"] || [];
        scores.push({
          value: data.score,
          unit: "none",
          recordedDate: data.Date,
          method: "none",
          type: "riskAssessment",
        });
        result["riskAssessment"] = scores;
        return result;
      }, []);
```

the output:

```
[riskAssessment: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] ]
```

Ive tried just using the index of `riskScoresFormatted[0]` that comes back undefined. `riskScoresFormatted.slice(1)` just returns an empty array. Ive also tried targeting the first Item like `riskScoresFormatted.riskAssessment` this works but the value is sometimes null so it causes bugs later down the line.

Comment: Why even use `.reduce()` here? Seems you want a plain `.map()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the final reduce argument from `[]` to `{}` and I think you'll have better luck.

```
const riskScoresFormatted = riskScores.datapoints.reduce((result, data) => {
  const scores = result["riskAssessment"] || [];
  scores.push({
    value: data.score,
    unit: "none",
    recordedDate: data.Date,
    method: "none",
    type: "riskAssessment",
  });
  result["riskAssessment"] = scores;
  return result;
}, {});
```

Or, use `Array.map()` instead:

```js
const riskScores = {
  count: 4,
  datapoints: [{
      Date: "2021-05-05",
      score: 0,
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-05-12",
      score: 0,
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-05-30",
      score: 0,
    },
    {
      Date: "2021-06-03",
      score: 114,
    },
  ],
};

var riskScoresFormatted = riskScores.datapoints.map((data) => ({
  value: data.score,
  unit: "none",
  recordedDate: data.Date,
  method: "none",
  type: "riskAssessment",
}));

console.log(riskScoresFormatted);
```

Comment: Mapping over this way works! Wow thanks ive been recking my brain for a while with this one.